# English "Please": 제발 vs 부탁해

Tags: translation, non-verbal-communication, written

When one wants to say in Korean, "pleeeease", the way we do in English when we might even add "pretty please with a cherry on top", `제발` seems like a common translation of `please`; however, I mostly hear that used the same as Google suggests (whiny and sarcastic):

[image]

I have heard `부탁드립니다` used in a way that seems like an authentic `please`.

Though my question is really just one question: *how does one translate a positive, non-sarcastic `please`?*, allow me to add to the question three slants that help guide answers to what I'm really looking for:

- are there more authentic and/or more cute/innocent ways of saying please?
- am I right in thinking that `제발` is simply rude and better left out of a positive/optimistic conversation?
- are there other ways to say/infer please that I should consider in verbal and/or written communications?

Comment: I think 제발 is not exactly rude, but rather *desperate*.  You'd say "제발 말 좀 들어라!" to an unruly three-year-old, or "제발 제 말 좀 들어주십시오!" to an officer who's about to throw you out, etc.  Something like "제발 밥 좀 주세요." would usually mean that you're starving to death.

Comment: 제발 is like 'I beg you!'

Answer (score 2):

Direct translations of `please` are `제발` or `부디`.
Simply speaking, however, do not use `제발` or `부디` in most cases.
When you say `제발`, you look like making you too lower than the hearer. `부디` is better but heard too old way.
Instead, you can use more modest expressions like `~(을)를 부탁드립니다`, `~(을)을 해주세요` or many others alike.

Comment: is `부디` mostly only a written adverb?

Comment: You may use it in verbal, but I have not been heard or spoken it for several tens years.

Answer (score 1):

- 부탁드립니다/부탁드리겠습니다 will be what you looking for. This is appropriate in almost every single circumstances.
- 제발 is not rude at all, but rather gives one an impression like this - 'The one who is saying '제발' is too desperate that he can do whatever he should, even if what he is going to do may damage his reputation - or anything negative.' This is why Nemo said "you look like making you too lower than the hearer". And I see jick's comment now... his explanation is great.
- Same answer as the first one.

Comment: i'm leaning towards this as the final answer as it appears to be more complete.  could you add something regarding this part of the discussion point, `are there any cute ways of saying "pleeeeeeease, with a cherry on top"?` - *부탁드립니다*